# Stop time for a few seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, pause

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="start" onClick="myFunction()">Start</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    for(i=3; i>0; i--) {
        console.log(i);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = i;
        pause(5000);
    }
}

function pause(milliseconds) {
    var dt = new Date();
    while ((new Date()) - dt <= milliseconds) { /* Do nothing */ }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Numbers 3, 2 and 1 appear in console at intervals of 5 seconds, but in div appear number 1 (actually all numbers) after 15 seconds. Why console is not synchronized with display? Exist other method to stop rime between instructions?

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) (note by googling "Stop time for a few seconds in javascript", you'll find plenty of answers!)

Comment: You are essentially blocking the whole thing, even browser repaints.

Comment: Infinite blocking loops are *almost never* a valid way to pause execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your function fails to work is, basically, that DOM changes arent processed and displayed until everything finishes running for a second. The easiest way to make it work would probably be a call to `setTimeout` which waits a specific amount of time then calls the supplied function. For example you could use the following function to make your code work.

This function recursively calls itself via a `setTimeout` call to make sure the DOM is udpated.

```js
function myFunction(i) {
  (function doStuff() {
    console.log(i);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = i;
    i -= 1;

    if (i >= 0) {
      setTimeout(doStuff, 5000);
    }
  }());
}

myFunction(3);
```

```html
<div>
  Counter: <span id="output">X</span>
</div>
```